# Allow void pointer arithmetic Android NDK clang

Tags: android, android-ndk, clang

I am moving from GCC to clang with NDK r13. I have a library that makes use of void pointer arithmetic, that would be very difficult to change.

```
    void * bar;
    void * foo;
    foo = bar + 1;
```

Gives the following error with clang, but not GCC:

> error: arithmetic on a pointer to void   foo = bar + 1;

Is there a way to enable the extension to allow void pointer arithmetic on this platform with clang, the same as GCC allows?